# Работа с диском int 13h bios

Tags: ассемблер, ос, bios, x86

На ассемблере NASM пишу 16-битную ОС. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: если попытаться загрузить с помощью прерывания BIOS int 13h сектор, адрес которого больше 63, то будет выдаваться ошибка (0x0C в QEMU или 0x02 на реальном компьютере). 
 Вот отрывок кода:

```
.....

mov al, 1
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 0x80
mov dh, 0
mov bx, [buf]
mov cx, 64 ;Если положить в cx число меньше 63, то все в порядке
int 0x13
jc error

.....

error:
 .hex_to_str:
   mov bh, 0x00
   mov al, ah
   and al, 0xF0
   shr al, 0x04
   mov bl, al
   mov al, [bx+hex_nums]
   mov [error_code_hex], al
   and ah, 0x0F
   mov bl, ah
   mov ah, [bx+hex_nums]
   mov [error_code_hex+1], ah
.err_print:
   mov si, error_boot
   call print
   mov ah, 0x00
   int 0x16
   int 0x19

print:
   mov ah, 0x0E
.lp:
   mov al, [si]
   cmp al, 0x00
   je .end
   mov bl, 0x02
   int 0x10
   inc si
   jmp .lp
.end:
   ret

error_boot:
     db 0x0A, 0x0D, "DISK READ FAIL :( ", 0x0A, 0x0D, "Error code: 0x"
error_code_hex:
    db '00', 0x0A, 0x0D

press_msg:
    db "Press any key to reboot...", 0x00
hex_nums:
    db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Вопрос: как получить доступ к секторам на диске, адрес которых больше 63?

UPD:
Решил использовать расширенные функции BIOS описанные в [этой статье](https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)#LBA_in_Extended_Mode).

Comment: А откуда у вас столько секторов ? Любой большой диск в наше время находится в LBA режиме, в котором держат количество логических секторов не больше 63, за счет увеличения количества логических головок. Вычисляйте место положения блока по формулам LBA с использованием большого кол-ва головок (до 255). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LBA Или используйте расширенные функции, если они доступны https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_(BIOS)

Comment: Вот ещё статья где всё подробно расписано: https://vxlab.info/wasm/article.php-article=1012001.htm

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

"...на самом деле BIOS вводит ограничение - цилиндров не больше 1024, секторов не больше 63, зато головок все 255."

[Источник](https://wasm.in/blogs/ata-dlja-dzenstvujuschix-chast-1.335/)